# When is it appropriate to have multiple top-level packages in a Python distribution?

Tags: python, packaging

I do not see many examples of multiple top-level package Python distributions. What are the advantages/disadvantages of doing this vs:

1. multi-distribution (each directory with its own setup.py, requirements etc. installed independently)
2. single top-level package, divided with modules/subpackages.

It seems like a multiple top-level package distribution avoids managing the metadata and other packaging infrastructure more than once when you have slightly-related code. This is probably less hassle overall and easier for new contributors to avoid a multi-distribution setup (which might require them to understand more about setuptools etc.). It comes at the cost of losing e.g. granular dependencies. However, a single top-level package using modules and subpackages for separation would have the same downside. Perhaps I am seeing a difference here that doesn't really exist?

I have some internal code that doesn't feel like one package - e.g. one large tool, a collection of smaller unrelated tools, and some shared datamodel and glue code. Other tools and libraries are likely to follow and I'd expect people to want access to the installed datamodel package/module for ad-hoc scripts as well.

For the sake of argument:

- datamodel and glue code is primarily about accessing data from config or a database, or some combination of sources.
- bigtool depends on all of this information and compiles/deploys it.
- utils might contain smaller tools to extract commonly-used summary statistics from the datamodel, or only tangentially use some common code for relatively unrelated tasks (check production server status etc.).
- ad-hoc scripts are often written that use datamodel. maybe later they become larger and get stored in utils or their own location.

Would a single distribution with a `bigtool`, `utils` and `datamodel` top-level packages make sense here? Or would most people have an emptyish package at the top-level (some overall project name), and just provide the separation via sub-packages? It is then possible to move to multi-distribution later if you have a need to build/install them independently for some reason (e.g. separating dependencies).

Comment: **(1)** To answer *Would a single distribution with a `bigtool`, `utils` and `datamodel` packages make sense here?* we need to know what it contains. Your description as-is is not enough **(2)** You'd be better off checking `django`, `flask` and other multi-packaged python distributions vs some single package distributions to see for your self why those were packaged as they were. IMO you'll get mixed answers with this question

Comment: I've described in general terms what they contain above. I don't understand the trade-offs vs the two primary alternatives, which is the main question. Would it help if that was at the end rather than the beginning?

Comment: I'm not sure what the general perception will be, but I know that `tool`, `collection`, `datamodel`, `glue code`, etc. are *relative* to the user. E.G. I might think a tool is a simple `find_in_str` function, while others will find a tool an entire module. All these definition are relevant to determine with accuracy if some project needs to be multi-packaged or not

Comment: Sorry but I'm lost with the terms package, multi-package and multi-distribution here. A Python package is a collection of modules. One wheel or egg artifact may have one or more modules, packages and subpackages. A Python project may be distributed in one or more artifacts. What are the two alternatives that you are comparing exactly?

Comment: Yes, they can - and a project can evolve. The question is a general one: when would you change your approach and why? I hardly ever see this setup, which makes it seem like there is no upside vs modules alone. Flask seems to be mostly single-package and it's not clear to me why flask.json has been separated. Same with Django.

Comment: @jdehesa 1) single top-level package, multiple modules/subpackages; 2) multiple top-level packages; 3) completely separate distributions (different setup.py). I should have been clearer that I primarly meant multiple top-level packages, will adjust.